# curl not working when url is redirected

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Last 2 days I'm trying to figure it out.

My script is extracting data(description, title, images from url - like facebook). It work fine on links without redirect. But when there is a redirection it fails.. - only on server(on localhost works fine always).
Example website I'm testing is - rogerwanke.com.

I tried many different scripts, but `curl_ini`, `curl_exec` always return timeout.
Same happens when I'm trying to use `get_headers()` or `get_file_contents()` functions. It always fail on my server.
Do you have any idea what can cause this problem? Maybe some php.ini configuration?

I use php 5.4 on server (same as localhost)
`Allow_url_fopen` is set to on.

Comment: Do you `FOLLOW_REDIRECT`?

Comment: Yes. I tried like 10 diffrent scripts for it.. all works on localhost nothing on my server

Comment: Please show your complete code

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

is that setting not working?

Comment: No still -> couldn't connect to host